# Sitecore identity server to parse Azure group claims coming back with specific URLdue to Group Overage Claim

Tags: identity-server, azure-ad

Some details:

1. Sitecore version 9.3
2. Using Sitecore Identity Server
3. Azure AD Integration

In the returned `ID_Token`, Azure is sending group URL details because of Group Overage Policy (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens), the user is mapped to more than 200 AD groups.

Here is the output:

```
{
  ...
  "_claim_names": {
   "groups": "src1"
    },
    {
  "_claim_sources": {
    "src1": {
        "endpoint":"[Url to get this user's group membership from]"
        }
       }
     }
  ...
 }
```

What is the efficient way to make another call to `Azure AD` to get all the groups and then filter out all the unwanted groups in Sitecore Identity Provider?

I already have `SecurityGroup` mapped in the manifest to return limited groups.

Thanks,
Mayank